# jQuery Isn't applying to my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not quite sure why it isn't working. I got the jQuery from the Google server and it just wont recognize my fadeOut.

Here's my html File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Prepare your Jimmies</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <body>
        <div id="loading">
            <p id="rj">Shh... No tears, Only Dreams Now</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the script.js file

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rj').fadeOut(100,'slow');
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Put "http:" in front of your script `src` value. Check your console for errors too.

Comment: whether the html file is loaded from local files sytem without a web server... with url `file://`

Comment: @marc http:// is really not necessary. you can leave it as it is, and it will be automatically be prepended with http: or https: depending on what you use on your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `fadeOut` takes two parameters, one timeout and one callback. So it should be:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rj').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

or

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rj').fadeOut(100);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're passing both `100` and `'slow'` to `fadeOut`.

As per [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), the first argument, duration, is:

> A string or number determining how long the animation will run.

Simply use "slow" OR 100, and you're fine:

```
$('#rj').fadeOut('slow');
```

or

```
$('#rj').fadeOut(100);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CSJ5D/1/)

(You'll notice that I did not include jqueryui in the fiddle.)

Comment: Followed what you said and just made it 'slow' and it still doesn't work. Could i not have linked the script file correctly?

Comment: @user2466564 The fiddle I added uses a copy/paste of your script link.  That line definitely is not your issue.  Maybe try using the fiddle as a starting point and merge in other parts of your code until you get the failure?

Comment: Alright this is what i have now but it still doesn't seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/5nfRm/

Comment: @user2466564 When I click run, I see the text fade out.  In what way is it not working?

Comment: It works on Fiddle for me. But Could it be because im trying to run it locally?

Comment: @user2466564 Are your results that you never see the div, or that you always see the div?  If it's never, it's fading faster than the page loads.  Set a much longer fade (e.g. `fadeOut(10000)`), and you'll see it.  If it's always, I have no idea.

Comment: Okay, when i uploaded it to my server it worked fined. It seems it just doesn't work locally. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2466564 It's likely your browser is configured to not allow javascript from local files.  That's often a safety feature.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the documentation, fadeOut take 2 arguments
the first is the duration of the animation, you can put 100 for 100ms or 'slow', the second argument is the function which was execute after your animation. 
[fadeOut Doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

So you line

```
$('#rj').fadeOut(100,'slow');
```

is wrong, you can write :

```
$('#rj').fadeOut('slow');
```

or

```
$('#rj').fadeOut(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

For easing you also have to include the jquery-ui library:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 'slow' is not a easing propetry. and 100 is very fast (1000 is 1 second). try if this works: `$('#rj').fadeOut('fast','linear');`

Comment: No, but it is for easing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using fadeOut wrong, it accepts a speed and a callback function, it looks as if you are trying to do a delay so try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rj').delay(100).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Also make sure your script is in the same folder as your HTML page as your source states.

Answer (score 0):

You have no head! ;)

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Prepare your Jimmies</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loading">
       <p id="rj">Shh... No tears, Only Dreams Now</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```